# Does the Directory class object cache information?

Tags: c#, directory, share

I was under the impression that the Directory class methods GetDirectories() and Exists() always get the current situation in a directory. But somehow that seems not to be true for file shares.

I'm repairing a complex background service that automatically copies files from a local directory to a share. Everything works just fine a long as I don't touch the files in the share.

For some reason when I delete files in the destination share the GetDirectories() and Exist() tell the service they are already there but they aren't.

The code below is a recursive routine that creates the destination directories in the same order as the source. But sometimes is just doesn't. I've tested the regular expressions which determine certain conditions and come to the conclusion that they work as expected so one of the .Success properties is correctly true. That's not where it is failing. The path does not contian the 'Quant....' strings either. So it should always create the directories.

I've tried to reproduce this locally but can't. It only happens on the production server after files have been deleted from the destination share.

The only conclusion I Can come up with is that the directory information for the share is cached somewhere. If I stop the service, delete the files and start the service again. Everything works perfectly. If I delete the files while service is running it crashes during copy with this exception:

> Could not find a part of the path
> '\\wur\dfs-root\PROJECTS\ESG_ERA_GLP\D0154234\1\NONGLP\2020\cpf\2020.okt26\cpf001.d\AcqData-CumulativeAuditTrail.xml'.

because part of the directorystructure was not created. If I look in the destination the directory starting with '2020.okt26' has not been created.

```
        private void CreateFolders(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
        {
            foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    var destFolder = (destinationPath + dirPath.Remove(0, _sourceRootFolder.Length));

                    if (!destFolder.HasRootLocks(destinationPath))
                    {
                        Match isGlpFolder = glpFolders.Match(dirPath);
                        Match isNonGLPFolder = nonglpFolders.Match(dirPath);
                        Match isNonGLPRootFolder = destNonglpRootFolders.Match(destFolder);
                        Match isGLPRootFolder = destGlpRootFolders.Match(destFolder);

                        destFolder = (destinationPath + dirPath.Remove(0, _sourceRootFolder.Length));

                        if ((isGlpFolder.Success || isNonGLPFolder.Success)
                            && !dirPath.Contains("QuantResults")
                            && !dirPath.Contains("QuantReports"))
                        {
                            if (!Directory.Exists(destFolder))
                            {
                                var di = Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);

                                if (isGLPRootFolder.Success)
                                {
                                    SetDirSec(destFolder, glpAccessRule, true);
                                }

                                if (isNonGLPRootFolder.Success)
                                {
                                    SetDirSec(destFolder, nonglpAccessRule, true);
                                }
                            }
                            Match isQuantFolder = quantFolders.Match(destFolder);

                            if (isGlpFolder.Success && isQuantFolder.Success)
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory($"{destFolder}\\QuantResults");
                                Directory.CreateDirectory($"{destFolder}\\QuantReports");
                            }
                        }
#if EXTRAINFO
                        else
                        {
                            Log.Info($"Did not create folder: {destFolder} GLP?:{isGlpFolder.Success} NONGLP?:{isNonGLPFolder.Success}");
                        }
#endif
                    }
                    CreateFolders(dirPath, destinationPath);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
                {
                    _glpDebugger.DebugMessage($"Fout bij folder {dirPath}. Error: {ex.Message}", true, true, false);
                    Log.Info($"CreateFolders: {ex.MessageEx()}");
                    continue;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _glpDebugger.DebugMessage($"Fout bij folder {dirPath}. Error: {ex.Message}", true, true, false);
                    Log.Info($"CreateFolders: {ex.MessageEx()}");
                    continue;
                }
                finally
                {
                    //continue on error
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: A network path... I don't think is .net what caches the data, it is more plausible that Windows is the one that caches it.

Comment: Yes, that's possible too. Is there a way to flush this cache?